# Full join and updating table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to updating a table in postgresql with other tables :

main table :

```
 id val1 val2 val3 val4
  1  50   30 
  2  3    69
  3  5         8   90    
  4  8    02
```

now, lets assume i have two sub tables :

```
table 1
id val1 val2
3        5

table 2
id val3 val4
1   8    90
4   55   99
5   30   7
```

So i can't figure out how to get the following table by joining or update the main table with table 1 and table 2 ? a simple full join would replace the val2(id=3) with none value :

```
 id val1 val2 val3 val4
  1  50   30   8    90
  2  3    69
  3  5    5    8   90    
  4  8    02   55  99
  5            30   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - join two source tables.

Select all `ids` from the tables using `union` and left join four columns from the tables. Use `distinct` in case there are the same `ids` in both tables.

```
select distinct id, val1, val2, val3, val4
from (
    select id
    from table_1
    union
    select id
    from table_2
    ) s
left join table_1 using(id)
left join table_2 using(id);

 id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 
----+------+------+------+------
  1 |      |      |    8 |   90
  3 |      |    5 |      |     
  4 |      |      |   55 |   99
  5 |      |      |   30 |    7
(4 rows)
```

Step 2 - insert new rows and update existing rows in the main table.

Use `with` statement, naming the resultset from step 1 as `source`.
As you have `ids` in the source tables which not exist in the main table, firstly you have to insert these new rows. Next update existing rows using `coalesce()` to update only non-null values:

```
with source as (
    select distinct id, val1, val2, val3, val4
    from (
        select id
        from table_1
        union
        select id
        from table_2
        ) s
    left join table_1 using(id)
    left join table_2 using(id)
    ),
new_rows as (
    insert into main_table
    select * from source
    where id not in (select id from main_table)
    )
update main_table m set
    val1 = coalesce(s.val1, m.val1),
    val2 = coalesce(s.val2, m.val2),
    val3 = coalesce(s.val3, m.val3),
    val4 = coalesce(s.val4, m.val4)
from source s
where s.id = m.id;
```

Check the result:

```
select * 
from main_table
order by 1;

 id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 
----+------+------+------+------
  1 |   50 |   30 |    8 |   90
  2 |    3 |   69 |      |     
  3 |    5 |    5 |    8 |   90
  4 |    8 |    2 |   55 |   99
  5 |      |      |   30 |    7
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you sir,, that's exactely what i was looking for :)